# Getting type error after update jointjs to 3.1.1 in an Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, jointjs

1. Created new Angular 9 project with just one component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as dagre from 'dagre';
import * as graphlib from 'graphlib';
import * as joint from 'jointjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-diagram',
  templateUrl: './diagram.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diagram.component.scss']
})
export class DiagramComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const graph = new joint.dia.Graph();

    const paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
      el: document.getElementById('my-holder'),
      model: graph,
      width: 600,
      height: 100,
      gridSize: 1,
      background: { color: 'cornflowerblue'}
    });

    joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle.define('examples.CustomRectangle', {
      attrs: {
        body: {
          rx: 10, // add a corner radius
          ry: 10,
          strokeWidth: 1,
          fill: 'cornflowerblue'
        },
        label: {
          textAnchor: 'left', // align text to left
          refX: 10, // offset text from right edge of model bbox
          fill: 'white',
          fontSize: 18,
          text: 'Hello'
        }
      }
    }, {
      // inherit joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle.markup
    }, {
      create() {
        const rectangle = new this();
        rectangle.resize(250, 50);
        return rectangle;
      }
    });
    const customRect = (joint.shapes as any).examples.CustomRectangle.create();
    customRect.addTo(graph);
  }

}
```

2.Install dependencies:

```
"backbone": "^1.4.0",
"dagre": "^0.8.5",
"jointjs": "^3.0.3",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.15",
```

3. Start application. Would expect to see the customRect. Chrome console shows an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'CustomRectangle' of undefined
    at DiagramComponent.ngOnInit (VM10 main.js:237)
    at callHook (VM11 vendor.js:11079)
    at callHooks (VM11 vendor.js:11043)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (VM11 vendor.js:10983)
    at refreshView (VM11 vendor.js:17422)
    at refreshComponent (VM11 vendor.js:18842)
    at refreshChildComponents (VM11 vendor.js:17133)
    at refreshView (VM11 vendor.js:17456)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (VM11 vendor.js:17530)
    at tickRootContext (VM11 vendor.js:19004)
```

Seems that the custom rect is not created. But going back to jointjs version 2.2.1 without any code changes, it works fine. Error is shown with any jointjs version >=3.0.0

Comment: here is the solution: https://github.com/clientIO/joint/issues/1281